# Why a post incremented value(say a++) gives different outputs when added to the variable(int a) and the value assigned to the variable?

Tags: c, increment, post-increment

```
int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 1, c = 1;
    int x = a + a++ ; 
    int y = 1 + b++ ; 
    int z = c++ + c++ ; 
    printf("%d\n %d\n %d\n", x, y, z);
}
```

Output:

```
   3
   2
   3
```

I know there are similar questions out there but nothing addressed my issue.
I'm basically doing the same thing in 2nd & 3rd lines of the main function . Why do I receive different outputs?

And all the materials I referred to so far said that post increments take place after the operations have taken place. In that case, shouldn't we assign `z` to c+c(i.e 1+1=2) and then increment the value of `c`?But clearly my logic is wrong. Can someone explain that too?

Comment: Undefined behaviour. Move on, or start coding in Java.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior)

Comment: @Thomas Jager I thought languages were perfect & kinda didn't know such a thing as undefined behavior existed. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Bathsheba I guess I'm moving on.. :|

Comment: Don't do that! You won't get paid as much! C is perfect insofar that it's multiplatform and blisteringly fast if used properly so it omits various useless bits of functionality that would otherwise kill runtime performance.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thats interesting.Maybe I should stick to C until i master the nitty gritties Thanks dude:)